# Process terminating with default action of signal 13 (SIGPIPE)

Tags: c, signals, system-calls, getline, lseek

I am trying to read the entire data written from the user in a buffer to process it inside my own shell "called hsh" but the process is terminated with signal 13:
Here is command that I passed to my shell:

```
valgrind echo "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   /bin/ls                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    " | ./hsh
```

And here are the results:

```
==203856== Process terminating with default action of signal 13 (SIGPIPE)
==203856==    at 0x4960077: write (write.c:26)
==203856==    by 0x48E0E8C: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1181)
==203856==    by 0x48E17A7: new_do_write (fileops.c:449)
==203856==    by 0x48E17A7: _IO_new_file_xsputn (fileops.c:1255)
==203856==    by 0x48E17A7: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1197)
==203856==    by 0x48E037F: fputs_unlocked (iofputs_u.c:37)
==203856==    by 0x10A7AE: ??? (in /usr/bin/echo)
==203856==    by 0x4876082: (below main) (libc-start.c:308)
==203856==
==203856== HEAP SUMMARY:
==203856==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==203856==   total heap usage: 228 allocs, 228 frees, 25,267 bytes allocated
==203856==
==203856== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==203856==
==203856== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==203856== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

here are my steps to read the data:

1. Use **lseek** to go to the end of file and count the number of bytes written
2. Use **lseek** again to go back to the start of the file
3. Allocate a buffer with this number of data + another byte for the null character
4. Read the data in chunks and store them in a temp buffer
5. Copy the data written into the temp buffer to the actual buffer
   However this method gives me a signal 13 (broken pipe signal ) and I don’t know why

This is my code:
Note: Every function that has underscore(_) in its name is implemented elsewhere and its prototype is declared in the "main.h" header file.

```
#include "main.h"
#define CHUNK_SIZE 1000

/**
 * _getlines - Read the command lines
 * @commands: The list where commands will be stored
 * Return: On success - number of commands
 *         On error - "-1"
 */
int _getlines(char **commands)
{
    char *line, *page, *chunk, ch, qoute;
    ssize_t bytes_read, total_bytes_read = 0;
    int j = 0, cmd_count = 0, i = 0, file_size;
    line = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    file_size = lseek(STDIN_FILENO, 0, SEEK_END);
    lseek(STDIN_FILENO, 0, SEEK_SET);
    page = malloc(file_size);
    if (page == NULL)
        return (-1);
    while ((bytes_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, line, CHUNK_SIZE) > 0))
    {
        _strcpy(page + total_bytes_read, line);
        total_bytes_read += bytes_read;
    }
    if (bytes_read == -1)
    {
        free(page);
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("%s\n", page);
    while (i < total_bytes_read)
    {
        ch = page[i++];
        if (ch == '\"' || ch == '\'')
        {
            line[j++] = ch;
            qoute = ch;
            do {
                ch = page[i++];
                line[j++] = ch;
            } while (ch != qoute);
        }
        else if (ch == '\n')
        {
            line[j++] = '\0';
            commands[cmd_count] = _strdup(line);
            j = 0;
            (cmd_count)++;
        }
        else
            line[j++] = ch;
    }
    if (cmd_count == 0)
    {
        commands[cmd_count] = _strdup(line);
        cmd_count++;
    }
    free(line);
    return (cmd_count);
}
```

Comment: For starters, `_strcpy(page + total_bytes_read, line);`... There's no guarantee that `line` is a null terminated C string. This function call can/could result in UB...

Comment: You can't use `strcpy` after a `read` because you can't ensure the data read has a 0x00 terminator that `str*` functions need. Use `memcpy` with a length of `bytes_read`

Answer (score 0):

While *mostly* neat and tidy code, there are many issues to be addressed. I've chopped away some bits to focus on lines with issues. (btw. Sending over 6000 SP's into your code will certainly cause `line` to overflow as characters are copied to its 1000 byte length.)

```
int _getlines(char **commands) // Unknown size of ptr array being populated

    char *line, *page, *chunk, ch, qoute; // Illegible block of declarations. "chunk" is unused.
    ssize_t bytes_read, total_bytes_read = 0;
    int j = 0, cmd_count = 0, i = 0, file_size; // "sizes" should be unsigned

    line = malloc(CHUNK_SIZE * sizeof(char)); // sizeof a char is 1. Don't multiply
    // Missing verification of success

    file_size = lseek(STDIN_FILENO, 0, SEEK_END); // Not needed

    page = malloc(file_size); // Did you mean "file_size + 1"?
    if (page == NULL)
        return (-1); // What about the allocation of "line"?

        _strcpy(page + total_bytes_read, line); // "line" is not a string!

    if (bytes_read == -1) {
        free(page); // What about the allocation of "line"?

    while (i < total_bytes_read) { // have to scroll back to verify i starts at 0
        if (ch == '\"' || ch == '\'') {
            line[j++] = ch; // No verification the j < size of line[]

                line[j++] = ch; // again, here
            } while (ch != qoute);

        else if (ch == '\n') {
            commands[cmd_count] = _strdup(line); // unnecessary allocation (see below)

            line[j++] = ch; // and again, here
    }

    if (cmd_count == 0) // Not sure about this...
    {
        commands[cmd_count] = _strdup(line); // line is NOT necessarily a C string
        cmd_count++;
    }
    free(line); // finally... but what about "page"?
    return (cmd_count); // return is not a function call. () unnecessary
```

There are a few too many troubles to "lightly touch" to correct.

The following corrects these problems with a rather major overhaul. This code has, at least, a few comments explaining its operation.

```
int _getlines(char **commands, unsigned sz) { // array max size available
    char k1024[ 1024 ], *page = NULL; // buffers here

    ssize_t total = 0;
    int i;
    while( ( i = read( STDIN_FILENO, k1024, sizeof k1024 ) > 0 ) ) {
        void *tmp = realloc( page, total + i + 1 ); // ongoing growth of input buffer
        if( tmp == NULL ) {
            // perhaps a diagnostic emitted here?
            free( page );
            return -1;
        }
        page = tmp;
        memcpy( page + total, k1024, i );
        total += i;
    }
    page[ total++ ] = 0; // terminate to form C string

    i = 0;
    while( isspace( page[ i ] ) ) i++; // toss away leading whitespace here
    if( !page[ i ] ) {
        free( page ); // that was a waste of time
        return 0;
    }

    if( i )
        memmove( page, page + i, total - i ); // shift everything to start of buffer

    int cmd_count = 0;
    commands[ cmd_count++ ] = page; // TODO: verify cmd_count doesn't exceed allowance

    char qch = 0;
    i = 0;
    while( page[i] )
        switch( page[i] ) {
            case '\"':
            case '\'':
                if( !qch )
                    qch = page[ i ];
                else if( page[ i ] == qch )
                    qch = 0;
                i++;
                break;
            case '\n':
                if( qch ) { i++; break; }
                page[ i++ ] = 0;
                if( page[ i ] )
                    commands[ cmd_count++ ] = page + i;  // TODO: verify cmd_count
                break;
            default:
                i++;
                break;
        }

    return cmd_count;
}
```

The caller need only `free( commands[0] )` to extinguish the entire block allocated. (Left to the reader to add the relevant headers.)

---

**EDIT**
Or... Perhaps the array of pointers to segments is meant to be dynamically allocated, too! Hard to say as the code calling this function has not been provided.

Comment: You didn’t use lseek why it is not needed?

Comment: Why not? Because this version reads "chunks" and adds them to a growing buffer (note: the call to `realloc()`...) Presuming the incoming data is reasonable (not 47 Tb!!), there's no need to "preallocate" a buffer of the expected size.